# How to turn on MSDTC programatically

Tags: windows

I know how to enable MSDTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) by using GUI - http://www.thereforesystems.com/turn-on-msdtc-windows-7/

Is there a way to do this automatically? I'd like to turn it on hundreds of systems and don't want to spend days doing it by hand. It could be stored in a registry key or turned on by WMI. I tried to google-up the solution but failed...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/04/17/577898.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Run **net start msdtc** in a command line or batch file.